# Closure of Interior

Tags: general-topology, field-theory, connectedness

Is it always true that for every set $S$ in $R^{n}$,  $\overline{(S^{0})} = \overline{S}$ equality holds? If true, my main strategy will be to prove that an arbitrary element $x$ in $\overline{(S^{0})}$ is also in $\overline{S}$ and vice-versa; however, I am also skeptical of the correctness of this statement. Does there exist any counterexample if it is false?

Comment: From the answers below, we get the lesson: Try a few simple examples.

Comment: I still can not understand why the closure of an empty set is again an empty set? I can not even understand conceptually why it is true!

Comment: First you have to figure out whether $\varnothing$ is a closed set.

Comment: How this result going to help for you?

Comment: @AnarRzayev: What do you think about the statement that the set $\mathbb{R}$ is open? If you can accept that, you should also believe that its complement $\emptyset$ is closed.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a \in \mathbb R^n$ and $S=\{a\}.$ Then

$$S^{0}= \emptyset , \overline{S^0}= \emptyset$$

and

$$ \overline{S}=S.$$

Answer (score 2):

A simple counter example would be $\mathbb Q$ - the LHS is the empty set, while the RHS is the entire real line.

Comment: Could you clarify details on how LHS is becoming empty set; in particular, why the closure of empty set is empty set again?

Comment: The closure of the empty set is itself since the empty set is closed by definition.